# Httpclient with SSL is working from Visual studio 2015\or from my Laptop but not working from windows server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I have simple application which is basically POST ( Postasnyc) message to RESTApi using HttpClient. .Net framework is .Net 4.5.2. This code is working fine from mylatop (WIndows 7), but it is not from Windows server 2012. I tried different windows server, no where it worked other than my laptop. But from the same server SOAPUI is working ( used the .pfx for SSL , created it from actual cert ). This is an issue with no clue.

Note: I have made sure the certs are installed on server.

I tried the following
1. Made sure no fire wall in between
2. Set Timeout for http client
3. ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy(); - didn't help
4. await client.PostAsync(objSearch.Resource, content).ConfigureAwait(false); - didnt help

Note: I have gone through so many forums, and tried almost all suggestions.

Code snippet is given below

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();

X509Certificate2 certificate = GetCertificateFromStore(); // getting the correct certs in server as well.

handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateRemoteCertificate);

        try
        {

            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls |  SecurityProtocolType.Tls11; 
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(objSearch.url);
                //client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 2147483647;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


                // HTTP GET
                //MessageBox.Show("Ready To post");
                // client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); - didnt work
                var response = await client.PostAsync(objSearch.Resource, content);
```

> Error Message. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred
>   while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
>   underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a
>   send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond. --->
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> at System.Net.PooledStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, TransportContext& context)    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>
> at RIBS.AccountService.PDFIntegrator.d__1.MoveNext()
>
> at RIBS.AccountService.PDFIntegrator.d__1.MoveNext()
>
> C:\Users\311827364\Source\Repos\RIBS_Net\Solution\RIBS.AccountService\PDFIntegrator.cs:line
>   142    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>
> at RIBS.AccountService.PDFStatementImpl.GetStatementList(String
>   strAccountNumber, String Transit, String accType, String strResource,
>   String stStartDate, String stEndDate) in
>
> C:\Users\311827364\Source\Repos\RIBS_Net\Solution\RIBS.AccountService\PDFStatementImpl.cs:line
>   23
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to get statement list from Ondemand
>
> at RIBS.AccountService.PDFIntegrator.d__1.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Users\311827364\Source\Repos\RIBS_Net\Solution\RIBS.AccountService\PDFIntegrator.cs:line
>   142<---

Comment: How did you implement ValidateRemoteCertificate? Did you check the firewall settings? That could also prevent a correct result.

Comment: Is there a proxy server at play? I've had issues before where a proxy server was needed.

Comment: Hi Jeroen Heier,  In ValidateRemoteCertificate i just added return true; I am saying yes to whatever comes in.

Comment: Hi Client, The URL i am using is F5(Load Balancer) URL, where F5 is been implemented as pass through, meaning no SSL check at F5 level.